# Why does modifying non-reactive property seem reactive in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my setup (Vue3), I have a class method that assigns a local, non-reactive object to a reactive object's property. Then, it immediately modifies the local object's property. Surprisingly, these changes are being detected by a Vue watcher, even though the local variable itself hasn't been made reactive with Vue's reactivity system.

```
<script setup>
import { reactive, watch } from 'vue';

class MyClass {
  data = null;

  assignAndUpdateImmediate() {
    const local_variable = { name: 'Immediate: initial' };
    this.data = local_variable;
    // This local variable is not reactive, but changing it is reflected in the watcher
    local_variable.name = 'Immediate: updated';
  }
}

const reactiveObject = reactive(new MyClass());

watch(() => reactiveObject.data?.name, (newName, oldName) => {
  console.log(`WATCHER: "${oldName}" -> "${newName}"`);
});

reactiveObject.assignAndUpdateImmediate();
</script>  

<template>
</template>
```

Output:
`WATCHER: "undefined" -> "Immediate: updated"`

[Try example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

---

If we introduce a delay after assigning the reactive member and before modifying the local variable, the change is not reflected in the watcher, as expected.

Output:
`WATCHER: "undefined" -> "Immediate: initial"`

[Try example with delay](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9k21r2zAQx7/KIQZJIEs2tldpmpGFwDpYO7qMvRGsin1xlMmSkeQ8YPzdd5LtNC1tIRDp7v53vzudKzYvitG+RDZhU5dYWXhw6MtixrXMC2M9VGBRJF7ucQgH4ZMt1LCxJoceyXpXXHOdKOEc/Dgt4n/FNUAqvIBr0KVSMQSAXDLTc53+LsiJN3mOqaRDf9AoABKjnQdlEqH+7oWVYq2QclSgRY4T6J0lE5BaeilUD2rKHrR+K92oLfo0QxswHsPHD7mDFJU4wRo3xiLkJpWbk9QZ6bHRQadrZDSMlczRlL5PoNezjhWeVRkFRqp9CVnGRtMwoyCoh0QwiJeaa/rR4GLH3Xzv1jtMPCXpDH2Nh26s/UGQch2foGV5Koztf4kgQwjS23gyKg2HR/hQ1BCxMln/4c98tfi2vJ8AZ++qNrTmDN7PoqXNQpaHUL5uGJ7Vff1lrwBC/HTcrBYtFV085oUiN92m44sLGzLvCG4js9HOGU0rGXk5S0xeSIX2rvCS4DmbdM/AmVDKHL5Hm7clDjt7ssXk3wv2nTsGG2c/LTq0e+Ts7PPCZugb9/LXLR7pfHbSrpS0FW8575EGWwbGJuxrqVPCvoiLtDfxw6KtW7nl0aN2XVMBNK5HjOeMPrDFG60/4n4afe7WitX/AcjHSIc=)

Why does modifying non-reactive property seem reactive in the first example?

I do understand that assigning the `local_variable` to `this.data` triggers the watcher, and that the Vue uses some `'tick'`-system to avoid unnecessarily frequent updates, but the value in the watcher should still be `"Immediate: initial"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use a callback watch, it creates a computed.

In your particular case when you call `reactiveObject.assignAndUpdateImmediate()` you call it on a reactive `this` and this particular line:

```
this.data = local_variable;
```

acts on a reactive object and triggers the computed to be re-evaluated and the corresponding watch callback.

If you change the `name` without accessing `reactiveObject` no watch is triggered:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { reactive, watch, ref } from 'vue';

class MyClass {
  data = null;

  assignAndUpdateImmediate() {
    const local_variable = global_variable;
    this.data = local_variable;
    // This local variable is not reactive, but changing it is reflected in the watcher
    local_variable.name = 'Immediate: updated';
  }
}

const global_variable = { name: 'Immediate: initial' };
const reactiveObject = reactive(new MyClass);

watch(() => reactiveObject.data?.name, (newName, oldName) => {
  $log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>WATCHER: "${oldName}" -> "${newName}"</div>`);
});

reactiveObject.assignAndUpdateImmediate();

</script>  

<template>
  <div id="$log"></div>
  <button @click="global_variable.name = 'New value'">Change name directy</button>
  <button @click="reactiveObject.data.name = 'New value'">Change name through reactiveObject</button>
</template>
```

The watch is identical to watch(computed(() => reactiveObject.data?.name)). so the callback is called only when dependencies are updated. In our case that's `reactiveObjec.data` (but not `.name` since no `name` exists at the first callback call).

A dependency is what VUE READS from the FIRST time. definitely .name is out the first time so it doesn't BECOME a dependency. The second time doesn't matter as well as any async code : vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect

If you call `assign...()` again and DONT change data the callback won't be called again :

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Yes, I understand this (pun not intended). But inside `assignAndUpdateImmediate()` we are modifying the local, non-reactive object `local_variable.name = 'Immediate: updated';` and since that operation happens after that same object is assigned to the class member, its new name value should not be reflected in the watcher.

Comment: @borndeprecated finally completed the answer

Comment: So if I understand correctly, modifying the reactive member notifies Vue that the value has changed, and when it comes time to execute the callbacks, the current value is used as the new value, regardless of what the new value was at the time of signalling.
I suppose it is bad practice then to mutate the unreactive objects if they are also referenced in a reactive object? Maybe I should explicitly initialize every variable as reactive?

Comment: the watch is identical to `watch(computed(() => reactiveObject.data?.name))`. so the callback is called only when dependencies are updated. In our case that's `reactiveObjec.data` (but not `.name` since no name exists at the first callback call`). If you call `assign...()` again and DONT change `data` the callback won't be called again (added the example to an answer)

Comment: I suppose it is bad practice then to mutate the unreactive objects if they are also referenced in a reactive object? = NO, as you see in the last example, the watch isn't triggered, triggered only the first time since you assigned `data`

Comment: Your answer does not exactly answer my question but it is somewhat helpful.
It doesn't explain why in the callback we see the value `'Immediate: updated'` when the callback is called at the point where the value is `'Immediate: initial'`.
"In our case [the dependency is] reactiveObjec.data but not .name" - This is slightly confusing because `reactiveObject.data.name` is still a dependency and when modified signals the watcher.
Regarding 'bad practice', callback not being called when the value referenced in a reactive object is changed, is exactly why I'd consider it 'bad practice'.

Comment: @borndeprecated actually the whole `reactiveObject` becomes a dependency and watched DEEPLY ‍♂️. i've just realized that. you can replace the watch with `watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('WATCHER: "${reactiveObject.data?.name}"');
});`